# display alert dialog push notification message sent through firebase console while app in background/foreground

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

i have been successfully receiving push notification sent through firebase console. Now, i am trying to display that notification message in an alert dialog box while clicking on that notification message. alert dialog is shown if app is opened but it just opens mainactivity while app is closed. so, requesting help to implement.

my code is as follows:
[image]
*MyFirebaseMessagingService.java*

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  @Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("merostock"));
    }



}


private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {

   Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra("msg",messageBody);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , resultIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"merostock");
    android.app.Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setTicker("Mero Stock").setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Mero Stock")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentText(messageBody).build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
}
```

*MainPage.java*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("msg") != null) {
        String caller = getIntent().getStringExtra("msg");
        Log.e("firebase message: ",caller);
        new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.NORMAL_TYPE)
                .setTitleText("Merostock")
                .setContentText(caller)
                .show();
    }
    }
```

Now, my app should display alert dialog anytime when push notification arrives and user click on that message. I tried so many options from online but couldn't implement. Let me know where i am missing.

Comment: I think you want something like WhatsApp? showing a dialog to reply shortcut when user tap on Notification while app is closed?

Comment: well, not like whatsApp. when push notification arrives, i want that content to be displayed as an alert dialog while user click that notification.